# Prove the upper bound of the minimum involving trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know if
$$\min\left(\begin{array}{c}
|\sin x|, |\sin y|, |\sin z|, |\cos x|, |\cos y|, |\cos z|, \\
|\sin(x-y)|, |\sin(x-z)|, |\sin(y-z)|,\\
|\cos(x-y)|, |\cos(x-z)|, |\cos(y-z)| 
\end{array}\right) \leq \frac25$$
for all real $x$, $y$, $z$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Better to write out the expression here, than to ask users to chase it offiste. There is help with formatting math, via the Help menu.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax formatting (See:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical terms. Avoid to use pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. In this case, it would probably help if you explained the origin of the problem. If it's a textbook exercise, say something about the topic(s) and technique(s) covered in the chapter. If it's a contest or challenge, say something about the intended audience. If it's your own conjecture, tell us what led you to the particular bounding value. Etc, etc, etc. In short, put as much effort into asking the question as you are hoping responders will put into answering it.

Comment: @Blue   The question is neither from any textbook exercise nor from any contest. However, I have done a large amount of numerical calculations but am not able to prove it. Any helpful answer to this seemingly elementary question would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  The question is regarding the upper bound on the minimums. Best regards.

Comment: @mooner: *"I have done a large amount of numerical calculations but am not able to prove it."* This kind of context should be included in the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may even be hidden.) Include any particular insights your calculations have provided (examples when the minimum attains the proposed bound, etc). This will save people from wasting time duplicating your effort. ... In any case, readers should know that they're confronting what amounts to an "open question", as this might not require a simple *answer* but actual *research*.

Comment: @SelrachDunbar: To restate: It's important to know whether someone has posted an *exercise* (which presumably has a straightforward solution) or a *conjecture* (which may not), to give the reader a heads-up that they *could* be facing something of a rabbit hole. (Fermat, anyone?) Moreover, it's helpful in the latter case for the asker to provide some reason to believe that the conjecture is even *plausible*. For all we know, the question as stated contains a typo, or the asker's methodology missed obvious counterexamples, etc. Also: *every* volunteer's time is precious and should be respected.

Comment: @Blue   Just wondering, which part of the question do you think might contain a typo? Thanks.

Comment: @mooner: (Comments aren't for discussion, so this may be my last one.) I'm speaking generally about best question-asking practices. Be that as it may ... I don't have any particular reason to suspect that your question isn't stated exactly as you intend, but I also haven't been given any particular reason to believe that what you intend has been properly thought-through. Showing something from the "large amounts of numerical calculation" you've done to justify your bound seems like the least you could do. Explaining your motivation may also help motivate others. ... Anyway, good luck to you!

Comment: I believe that the $2/5$ is a red herring, and that $k:=\sin(\pi/8)=0.38\ldots$ is the "proper" bound here. On the unit circle, "color" $\pi/8$-length arcs in order A, B, C, A, A, B, C, A, A, B, C, A, A, B, C, A, with "A"s touching the axes, and with endpoints of each arc receiving either adjacent color. Any "A"-color point defines an angle $x$ with either $|\sin x|$ or $|\cos x|$ at most $k$. Otherwise, pigeonholing guarantees that at least two of any three points share color "B" or "C"; the defined angles (say, $x$ and $y$) are such that either $|\sin(x-y)|$ or $|\cos(x-y)|$ is at most $k$.

Comment: @mooner:  I enjoyed thinking about this problem.  Did you close this question or did someone else?  I have a nice solution (that bypasses inverse trig functions) but I am not able to share.  It begins with the observation that if we define
$$ S_{xyz} := \{\text{the set of 12 outputs when all expressions above are evaluated at } x, y, \text{ and } z \}$$
then $S_{xyz} = S_{x'yz}$ where $x' = x \pm \pi/2 $.  So, by iteration, we may replace $x, y, z$ with $x', y', z'$ where the latter are all in the interval $[0, \pi/2)$.  Since $\cos(a) = \sin(\pi/2 - a)$, we may rewrite all expressions . . .

Comment: @Blue I think the question was clear enough, and the motivation, while a little muddled (as you noted, there is no indication of how the numerical examples were chosen), seems plausible. I would like to see the question reopened and your solution posted as a regular answer. I see we also have a third proposed solution; I'd be pleased to see it too.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is that for every $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, at least one of the following inequalities is true:
\begin{align}\newcommand{ab}[1]{\lvert{#1}\rvert}
\ab{\sin x} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\sin y} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\sin z} &\leq \tfrac25, \\
\ab{\cos x} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\cos y} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\cos z} &\leq \tfrac25, \\
\ab{\sin(x - y)} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\sin(x - z)} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\sin(y - z)} &\leq \tfrac25, \\
\ab{\cos(x - y)} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\cos(x - z)} &\leq \tfrac25, & 
\ab{\cos(y - z)} &\leq \tfrac25.
\end{align}

Let's prove this by proving the following stronger proposition: for every $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, at least one of the following inequalities is true:
\begin{align}\newcommand{sinp}{\sin\left(\tfrac\pi8\right)}
\ab{\sin x} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin y} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin z} &\leq \sinp, \\
\ab{\sin(x - y)} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin(x - z)} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin(y - z)} &\leq \sinp,
\end{align}

The second proposition is strictly stronger than the first because
$\sinp < \tfrac25$.

The second proposition can be proved by contradiction. Suppose that for some $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$
the claim is false. Then for these particular numbers $x,y,z,$ all of the following must be true:
\begin{align}
\ab{\sin x} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin y} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin z} &> \sinp, \\
\ab{\cos x} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos y} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos z} &> \sinp, \\
\ab{\sin(x - y)} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin(x - z)} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\sin(y - z)} &> \sinp, \\
\ab{\cos(x - y)} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos(x - z)} &> \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos(y - z)} &> \sinp.
\end{align}

Let $k$ be an integer and $x_0$ a real number such that $x = x_0 + \frac{k\pi}{2}$
and $0 \leq x_0 < \frac\pi2.$
Note that if $\sin x_0 \leq \sinp$ then $\ab{\sin x} \leq \sinp$.
So the assumption that the claim is false implies
$\ab{\sin x} > \sinp$,
which implies that $\sin x_0 > \sinp$,
which in turn implies that
$$ \frac\pi8 < x_0 < \frac{3\pi}{8}. $$

The same logic applies to $y$ and $z$ as well. Let $m, n$ be integers and
$y_0, z_0$ be real numbers such that
$y = y_0 + \frac{m\pi}{2}$, $0 \leq y_0 < \frac\pi2$,
$z = z_0 + \frac{n\pi}{2}$, and $0 \leq z_0 < \frac\pi2.$ Then
\begin{align}
\frac\pi8 &< y_0 < \frac{3\pi}{8}, \\
\frac\pi8 &< z_0 < \frac{3\pi}{8}.
\end{align}

Without loss of generality, we can assume $x_0 \geq y_0 \geq z_0.$
Then $x_0 - y_0$ is a real number
such that $x - y = x_0 - y_0 + \frac{(k - m)\pi}{2}$ and
$0 \leq x_0 - y_0 < \frac\pi2.$
The assumption that the claim is false then implies
$\ab{\sin(x - y)} > \sinp$,
which implies that
$\sin (x_0 - y_0) > \sinp$.
In particular,
$$ x_0 - y_0 > \frac\pi8. $$

For similar reasons,
$$ y_0 - z_0 > \frac\pi8. $$

We therefore have
$$ y_0 > z_0 + \frac\pi8 $$
and
$$
\frac{3\pi}{8} > x_0 > y_0 + \frac\pi8 > z_0 + \frac{2\pi}{8}
 > \frac{3\pi}{8},
$$

in short, $\frac{3\pi}{8} > \frac{3\pi}{8},$
which contradicts the assumption that the claim was false.
Therefore the claim is true.

A similar argument can show that for every $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, at least one of the following inequalities is true:
\begin{align}
\ab{\cos x} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos y} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos z} &\leq \sinp, \\
\ab{\cos(x - y)} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos(x - z)} &\leq \sinp, & 
\ab{\cos(y - z)} &\leq \sinp.
\end{align}
Hint: let $-\tfrac\pi2 < x_0 \leq \tfrac\pi2.$

Comment: I enjoyed thinking about this problem. Is it standard to close such (nice) questions after someone has posted an acceptable answer?  I have a nice solution (that bypasses inverse trig functions) but I am not able to share.  It begins with the observation that if we define
$$ S_{xyz} := \{\text{the set of outputs when all expressions above are evaluated at } x, y, \text{ and } z \}$$
then $S_{xyz} = S_{x'yz}$ where $x' = x \pm \pi/2 $.  So, by iteration, we may replace $x, y, z$ with $x', y', z'$ where the latter are all in the interval $[0, \pi/2)$.  Since $\cos(a) = \sin(\pi/2 - a)$ . . .

Comment: @SelrachDunbar As Blue pointed out a few hours after I first posted an answer, the bound can be tightened to $\sin\left(\tfrac\pi8\right)$ instead of $\tfrac25,$ and it is easy to see that the bounds of $x_0$ can be expressed as multiples of $\tfrac\pi8$ rather than invoking the arcsin function.